# Cómo estructurar una mutación para conectar con Django

Tags: django, vue.js, graphql

Estoy teniendo problemas para hacer consultas, crear, actualizar y eliminar objetos en Django GraphQL a través del plugin GraphQL de Vuex ORM.

Desde la interfaz que me provee Django para ejecutar las consultas puedo hacer uso de mis mutaciones y consultar por cualquier objeto en particular o cualquier colección de los mismos.

Les escribo un ejemplo de cómo creo un objeto desde la interfaz de Django:

```
mutation myMutation {
  createTipoProducto(input: {nombre:"Pizza", descripcion:"foobar"}) {
    tipoProducto {nombre, descripcion}
    status
  }
}
```

Este código me devuelve el objeto con sus atributos y un status 200 si fue exitosa la consulta.

Éstas son las clases en mi esquema('schema'):

```
class TipoProductoNode(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = TipoProducto
        filter_fields = ['nombre', 'productos']
        interfaces = (relay.Node, )

class TipoProducto(graphene.ObjectType):
    nombre = graphene.String()
    descripcion = graphene.String()

class CreateTipoProducto(graphene.ClientIDMutation):

    class Input:
        nombre = graphene.String(required=True)
        descripcion = graphene.String(required=True)

    tipo_producto = graphene.Field(TipoProducto)
    status = graphene.Int()
    ok = graphene.Boolean()

    def mutate_and_get_payload(self, info, nombre, descripcion, client_id_mutation=None):
    tipo_producto = TipoProductoNode._meta.model(nombre=nombre, descripcion=descripcion)
    tipo_producto.save()
    return CreateTipoProducto(tipo_producto=tipo_producto, ok=bool(tipo_producto.id), status=200)
```

Mi modelo declarado en Vuex ORM:

```
import { Model } from '@vuex-orm/core';
import Product from './Product'

export default class TipProd extends Model {
    static entity = "tipProds"

    static fields () {
    return {
        id: this.increment(),
        nombre: this.attr(''),
        descripcion: this.attr(''),

        producto: this.hasMany(Product, 'tipProd_id')
        }
    }
}
```

Éste es el método que intenté usar desde Vuex ORM para crear un nuevo objeto:

```
"TipoProducto"
     methods: {
         async register (tipProduct) {
            await TipProd.insert({
                data: 
                    tipProduct         
            });
            const tipProd = TipProd.query().last()
            await tipProd.$mutate({ name: 'createTipoProducto' });
}
```

Los atributos correctos que están guardados en "tipProd" fueron tomados de un form, por eso no los incluyo explícitamente

No encuentro la manera que Vuex ORM me estructure correctamente la consulta para crear un objeto (entre otras mutaciones que no puedo usar). ¿Qué es lo que estoy haciendo mal?

Intenté ver con Apollo devtools cuál es la consulta que genera Vuex ORM pero no logré que me funcionara, así que estoy un poco ciego de cómo me está estructurando la consulta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La estructura estaba bien, no podía ver la query saliente porque no había ninguna, me fallaba la conexión entre Django Graphene y Vuex-ORM plugin Graphql, ya que del lado de la API tenia mal definidas las mutaciones.